# Saving NSArray to NSUserDefaults and getting it in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

How can I save `NSArray` in `NSUserDefaults` and then load it back in an `NSMutableArray` to populate the `UIPickerView`?

Also the issue is that new values would be added to that `NSMutableArray` and then that array will be converted to `NSArray` to be saved in `NSUserDefaults` (as `NSMutableArray` can't be saved in `NSUserDefaults`).

Any help appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: `NSMutableArray` can be stored since it inherits properties of `NSArray`.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:yourMutableArray forKey:@"Key"];
```

A mutable array can be stored since it is a subclass of NSArray.

To get the value as an NSMutableArray:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Key"]];
```

or

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Key"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Thanx Vignesh, But what if some string value is changed like if there is a value in the array "one the road" and it gets updated as "on the road rite now" then how can we handle this, so that the same string would be updated in nsuserdefaults too, because the next time new updated array will be populated in picker view. is it possible

Comment: @illoGicalError. Welcome.You will have to update your NSUserDefaults with the modified array. You can store the updated array using first line of code.

Comment: That's it? No archieving, etc. Also can the array contain complex objects? What kind of objects can be stored?

Comment: For complex objects you got to use archiving. NSUserDafaults won't know how to marshal your object.

Comment: That arrayWithArray method was the key for me, I was trying various kinds of getters to set the array directly to the object read from userdefaults. Thanks Vignesh!

Answer (score 10):

```
// Store it
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:yourMutableArray forKey:@"Key"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

// Read it back
    NSMutableArray* myMutableArrayAgain = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Key"]];
```

Answer (score 4):

To convert from NSArray to NSMutableArray:

```
[array mutableCopy];
```

To convert from NSMutableArray to NSArray:

```
[NSArray arrayWithArray:array];
```

Edit: mutableCopy will need a release later, since it is a `copy`.

Comment: also to convert mutable to non-mutable you can do:
    [mutableArray copy];

Answer (score 2):

Obtain `NSMutableArray` instance using `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:]` after recovering `NSArray` from `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score 2):

As this question is being viewed by many new iOS developers. I want to add more to help newbie's.

```
-(void)arraysFunction:(NSArray*)array  mutArray:(NSMutableArray*)mArray{

    if (array == nil || [array count] == 0)  {

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:mArray forKey:@"mutableArray"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        NSLog(@"Mutable Array: %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"mutableArray"]);

        NSArray * simpleArray = [ NSArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"mutableArray"]];

        NSLog(@"Simple Array: %@", simpleArray);
    }
    else{

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:array forKey:@"array"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        NSLog(@"Simple Array: %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"array"]);

        NSMutableArray * mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"array"] mutableCopy]];

        NSLog(@"Mutable Array: %@", mutableArray);
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you to save `NSArray` into `NSUserDefaults` and then retrieving it as `NSMutableArray` vice versa.

You can call this method like:

```
NSArray * array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"C", nil];
    NSMutableArray * mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"D", @"E", @"F", nil];

    [self arraysFunction:array mutArray:nil];
    [self arraysFunction:nil mutArray:mutableArray];
```