# Save value into UserDefaults when app awake from iBeacon region

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

I try to save when user enters and exits an iBeacon Region. My app is correctly awake from background and the delegate method is called (it shows a LocalNotification). In this method I also try to save an object into `UserDefaults`.

In foreground it works perfectly. But when my app is turned off (from the tasks manager) and user enters or exits iBeacon Region, the LocalNotification is send (so the method is called), but it seems nothing is saved into UserDefaults. Because when the app is open again (by the user), I try to get back from UserDefaults what I've saved in background.

Here is my code :

```
// When user enters iBeacon Region
- (void)startTrip {
    // Check if a trip was already started
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDictionary *currentTrip = [userDefaults dictionaryForKey:kSTORECURRENTTRIP];

    if (currentTrip != nil) {
        // A trip is already running
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"entered beacon");

    // Create new trip
    currentTrip = @{@"startDateTime": @([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970])};

    // Store it into UserDefaults
    [userDefaults setObject:currentTrip forKey:kSTORECURRENTTRIP];
    [userDefaults synchronize];

    // Notification
    [Tools sendLocalNotificationWithMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Trip started at %@", [currentTrip valueForKey:@"startDateTime"]]];

}

// When user exits iBeacon Region
- (void)stopTrip {
    // Check if a trip was started
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDictionary *tmp = [userDefaults dictionaryForKey:kSTORECURRENTTRIP];

    if (tmp == nil) {
        // There is no current trip
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"exited beacon");

    // Finish Trip (set values)
    NSMutableDictionary *currentTrip = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:tmp];
    [currentTrip setObject:@([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]) forKey:@"stopDateTime"];

    // Add Trip to array of Trips to save
    NSMutableArray *tripsToSave = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[userDefaults arrayForKey:kTRIPSTOSAVE]];
    if (tripsToSave == nil) {
        tripsToSave = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    [tripsToSave addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:currentTrip]];
    [userDefaults setObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:tripsToSave] forKey:kTRIPSTOSAVE];

    // Reset stored current trip.
    [userDefaults removeObjectForKey:kSTORECURRENTTRIP];

    // Synchronize
    [userDefaults synchronize];

    // Notification
    [Tools sendLocalNotificationWithMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Trip finished at %@", [currentTrip valueForKey:@"stopDateTime"]]];
}
```

My questions are :

1. How long can I execute code when app is in background ? Is there a better way to do it (like async block ?)
2. Is it allowed to save into `UserDefaults` and is it possible to get back values saved into ?
3. `UserDefaults` is the same in background or foreground mode, no ?

EDIT : new code

Comment: What are the implementations of your defaults convenience methods?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have my computer now. But I think it's how I get and store my array. I try to use another way and give a feedback here.

Comment: I've edited my first question and added all the code when user enters and exits iBeacon Region. I've changed a lot about getting et storing the value. I don't save a Trip object but a NSDictionary. Unfortunately it still doesn't work ...

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific questions:

1. You have 10 seconds of time to execute in the background after a region entry/exit event.
2. Yes, you can save to UserDefaults during this time.
3. There is no difference in the background.

I suspect something is wrong with the code that saves to UserDefaults.  It is not obvious to me what is wrong.  I would:

1. Add NSLog statements to figure out what code gets executed.  Post the results of that as an edit to your question.
2. Test this same code block in the foreground triggered manually (not by a beacon) and verify it works.

Comment: Yes it works in foreground, my "Trip" object is saved into `UserDefaults` and I can get it back. In background it's more difficult to test it but the LocalNotification is sent and shown on iPhone screen so the code is executed. I agree with you, something should be wrong with my code ... But it's hard to test because it's only in background.

Comment: I've added some logs. I can confirm, currentTrip is not nil and array tripsToSave contains one object. The storeObjectIntoUserDefaults is call and there is a synchronize inside. And it works in foreground. When I want to get the array stored using its key, I get a nil object.

Answer (score 0):

I worry about these two lines:

```
[Tools storeObjectIntoUserDefaults:tripsToSave withKey:kTRIPSTOSAVE];

// Reset stored current trip.
[Tools resetObjectIntoUserDefaultsWithKey:kSTORECURRENTTRIP];
```

You mention in a comment to my other answer that `synchronize` is called inside the first method.  Are you absolutely sure?  Because if not this may cause the symptoms you describe.

The second line has no obvious purpose in the code snippet, as there is no line where the key is stored.  It seems there is a lot going on outside the code you posted, and the problem may be in the code we cannot see.

I suggest simplifying the code so the storage logic (including the synchronization) happens in the same place.

Comment: I think you're right. I've investigate and I think it's how I store and get my array that causes problem. My Trip object it's ok and it's made by those two methods. But it's not the same way to do with array. I will try this way : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9212596 but I don't have my computer now. But it doesn't explain why it's working in foreground... I will give you a feedback as soon as possible.

Comment: Calling synchronize shouldn't be necessary in any of these scenarios.

Comment: I've modified my code to store with another way (look at my edited question). But still doesn't work. So I've managed to save tripsToSave array into a file. But logs shows me that when this code is executed : NSArray *arrayToFile = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tripsToSave]; [arrayToFile writeToFile:path atomically:YES]; response is NO ... Again, in foreground it works return YES and everything works.