# How to save in Nsuserdefault as a subvalues of a particular value

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

```
    Work  
      - Speak with Client
      -Staff meeting
      -Project Delivery

    Home
      -Buy Milk
      -Pickup Your Son
      -Fill Out Water Tank

    Personal

      -Check Diabetes
      -Eat medicines
      -Do Exercise

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:@"Speak with Client"forKey:@“Work"];
```

I want to save it like under work I required `["Speak with Client","Staff meeting","Project Delivery"]`

**Example**

In Work task list I should have [speak with client,Staff Meeting, Project Delivery]

```
In Home task list I should have [Buy Milk,Pickup your son, fill out water tank]
```

How can I save this in Nsuser Default?

Comment: Start accepting answers for your previous questions. That way it will tend others to answer your questions.

Comment: This is not a good usage of `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving NSArray to NSUserDefaults and getting it in NSMutableArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212430/saving-nsarray-to-nsuserdefaults-and-getting-it-in-nsmutablearray)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the value you can set it as object.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:yourWorkArray forKey:"Work"];
```

From Documentation of [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setObject:forKey:)

```
- (void)setObject:(id)value
           forKey:(NSString *)defaultName
```

> The value parameter can be only property list objects: NSData,
>   NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. For NSArray and
>   NSDictionary objects, their contents must be property list objects.